# memory increase in meego when use PageStack

Tags: memory, qml, meego

When I use pagestack to move between pages, the memory of device increases.

Please see [memory increase when use PageStack](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/44808-memory-increase-when-use-PageStack) to see more clearly my problem

Comment: I think that as long as you pop pages, the garbage collector will take care of them eventually. Or do you always go forward?

Comment: Yes , I think that when use pagestack.pop to come back previous page then memory is decrease but not. This means that we must accept the fact that memory can not reduce. correct or incorrect? Do you have a solution for this problem?

Comment: In my opinion, the fact that the memory isn't destroyed right away after you do pagestack.pop means that maybe it will be garbage collected later on, so you don't have to worry about it. If it never garbage collects (it will garbage collect only if it needs to, probably), then that's a bug, but otherwise you shouldn't worry about it. If you're still concerned, you could try allocating/deallocating objects manually, but you should do so only if you have real problems.